# android.dexOptions.incremental property is deprecated

Tags: android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin

When trying to run gradle build, I get following warning in Android Studio 2.2
:

**Warning:The `android.dexOptions.incremental` property is deprecated and it has no effect on the build process.**

[image]

In build.gradle file here I have declare dexOptions

```
dexOptions {
   incremental true
   jumboMode = true
}
```

If it is deprecated then what is the alternate option of this attribute.

Comment: just remove the incremental true line at inside dexOptions block  because its a deprecated one

Answer (score 115, accepted):

By default `incremental` is turned on Java compilation in 2.1.0-rc1 (2016/4/22) or later. So its redundant to declare it in build.gradle file.

Answer (score 18):

## Changes in `Gradle 2.1.0-rc1`  (2016/4/22) or later.

**1.** Remove deprecated `dexOptions.incremental`. Incremental Java compilation is ON by default.

**2.** No need to write `jumboMode` too, Jumbo mode is ON by default in instant-run mode.

#### First stable v2.1.0 (2016/4/26)

Visit official gradle site for [more details](http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system)

#### Edit: 27/01/2017

### Instant Run changes

Android Studio 2.3 Canary 3 and newer has change to how Instant Run works.

Applying changes to a running applications is no longer tied to the [image: play.png] Run button. The Run button will now always perform an application restart. To apply code and resource changes in the running process, there is a new [image: hot-reload.png] button right next to it,  "Apply Changes", which attempts to hotswap the changes into the app. -> [ref](http://tools.android.com/recent/androidstudio23canary3isnowavailable)

So that `jumboMode` may not effect from run button. thanks

[image: toolbar]

Answer (score 3):

Solve Problem after removing 
**deprecated**

`dexOptions
{
   incremental true
}`

Incremental Java compilation is ON by default.