# ANDROID STUDIO 3.0 upgrade : gradle upgrade : sync failed

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, android-studio-3.0

I found this warning after upgrading the latest android studio  stable version  Warning:The `android.dexOptions.incremental` property is deprecated and it has no effect on the build process. how to resolve it ?

Comment: Go to the gradle file and delete   dexOptions { incremental true }, it's no longer needed since 2016/4/22 because i'ts implemented by default

Comment: can you add it as a response for the question to make it helpful and useful :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As JMedinilla mentioned:

> Go to the gradle file and delete `dexOptions { incremental true }`, it's no longer needed since `2016/4/22` because it's implemented by default. [Learn more](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37522668/android-dexoptions-incremental-property-is-deprecated/)

**More Information for troubleshooting gradle errors in AS 3.0**

I'm also facing some issues with gradle after upgrading to AS 3.0 today, please take a look at this [documentation page](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/gradle-plugin-3-0-0-migration.html) this solves my issue.

**For more updates about AS 3.0 check out these videos**

1. [AS 3.0](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0n9sBgds-Hs)
2. [Java 8 support](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LhaSi6_i2bo)
3. [The new Profiler](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6hTC-fcVPtk)